# 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute - Django

Tags: django

Very new to Django - I apologise in advance for the poor description!

I have two django models:

```
class Suite(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    client_name = models.ForeignKey(Client, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('courses:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

@property
def lessons(self):
    return self.portfolioupdate_set.all().order_by('position')


class PortfolioUpdate(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    suite = models.ForeignKey(Suite, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    # suite = models.ManyToManyField(Suite)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    video_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('courses:lesson-detail',
                       kwargs={
                           'course_slug': self.suite.slug,
                           'lesson_slug': self.slug
                       })
```

I am rendering the list of Portfolio Updates in the following way:

```
class PortfolioUpdateListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    def get(self, request, course_slug, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        suite = get_object_or_404(Suite, adviser__user=user, slug=course_slug)
        context = {'object': suite}
        return render(request, "courses/lesson_list.html", context)
```

I would like to have the 'suite' field, as a ManyToManyField, rather than a ForeignKey, so that a portfolio update can relate to many suites, rather than a portfolio update relating to a single suite. When I change this in models, and try to render the page, I get 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'slug'.

Is what I have described possible, and if so how would I render this? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: If you use a `ManyToManyField`, then `self.suite.slug` does not make much sense, since `self.suite` links to a many-to-many field with zero, one, or more `Suite`s, and a collection thus has *no* `.slug` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to have the 'suite' field, as a ManyToManyField, rather than a ForeignKey, so that a portfolio update can relate to many suites, rather than a portfolio update relating to a single suite. When I change this in models, and try to render the page, I get 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'slug'.

This is due to your `get_absolute_url` method:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse(
        'courses:lesson-detail',
        kwargs={
            #  .slug for .suite?  ↓
            'course_slug': self.suite.slug,
            'lesson_slug': self.slug
        }
    )
```

Indeed, if you change `suite` to a `ManyToManyField`, then that means that a `PortfolioUpdate` links to zero, one or more `Suite`s. But you can not get the `.slug` of a collection of `Suite`s, since there can be zero `Suite`s, or multiple ones where the `Suite`s will have all different slugs.

Likely the best way to fix this is to remove the `course_slug` from the URL pattern and thus from the `reverse` call as well.

Comment: That's very well explained and makes perfect sense, thank you. I am using course_slug frequently to navigate between the pages of different suites. What would be the optimal way to do this, while still allowing for the ManyToMany relationship mentioned above?